# Trouble with character encoding using emacs in windows 7 on Parallels in OSX

Tags: windows, emacs, character-encoding, parallels

A lot on my plate here, I know. I'm trying to get emacs set up in paralells, and running into some strange issues.  Take the following code as an example:

```
(setq mac-command-modifier 'super)
(global-set-key (kbd "s-z") 'backward-char)
(global-set-key (kbd "s-a") 'mark-whole-buffer)
```

If I paste this into the emacs window from OSX, it interprets fine. If, in the emacs window I edit it, so that it says, for instance

```
(setq mac-command-modifier 'super)
(global-set-key (kbd "s-z") 'backward-char)
(global-set-key (kbd "s-b") 'mark-whole-buffer)
```

I get an error *void variable s-b*. If I paste the whole mess back to coda and then back into emacs it interprets fine again.

Any thoughts on steps to solve this?

Comment: That sounds like the double quotes around `s-b` have disappeared.  Double-check that they're still there, and haven't turned into "smartquotes" or something else.

Comment: I have no clue of what the problem might be, but maybe following syntax could help you either workaround it or add more troubleshooting info: `(global-set-key [(super a)] 'mark-whole-buffer)`

Comment: juanleon - this, again, works when pasted but throws 'void-variable c'  when I replace a with c in the emacs buffer :/